# JMol "calculate HBONDS": which atom is the donor/acceptor?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, structural-biology, software

JMol can be used to identify Hydrogen bonds in proteins by the script "calculate HBONDS".  By outputting the state of the network, we can obtain a lisdt of H-bonds.

Here's one line from an example output (PDB ID number 1a1x):

```
74    540    4096    0.001    -2.507   hbond;
```

I believe the correct interpretation of the first two numbers is that atom 74 is H-bonded to atom 540.  (I'm not really sure what the other numbers mean.)

> **Question**: How can we determine which atom is the donor and which is the acceptor?

In the above example, atom 74 is a Nitrogen atom and atom 540 is a Carbon atom, so presumably the Nitrogen atom is the donor.  But, how can we tell in general?

Answer (score 3):

I dont know about JMol, but this can be easily done with UCSF Chimera.

I loaded the 1a1x structure.
Then selected: Tools > Structure Analysis > FindHBond

I kept the default values and selected `Write information to reply log`

Then clicked `OK`

On the structure the H Bonds will be identified with a coloured line.

To view which is the donor and acceptor go to: Favorites > Reply log

An output of the reply log is below:

```
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
ASP 12.A N    GLU 25.A OE2  no hydrogen  3.012  N/A
HIS 13.A N    GLU 25.A OE1  no hydrogen  3.338  N/A
HIS 13.A ND1  ASP 12.A OD2  no hydrogen  2.835  N/A
LEU 14.A N    TRP 70.A O    no hydrogen  2.934  N/A
TRP 15.A N    ARG 23.A O    no hydrogen  2.866  N/A
...
120 hydrogen bonds found
```

As you can see the donor and acceptor has been identified as defined in the header line.

If you wish, the information can also be written to a file by selecteing `Write to text file` in the `FindHBond` window.

Answer (score 3):

I also had to do the same using Jmol, and I figured it out how to get a list of all the hbonds.

Step 1: Calculate the hbonds with or without RASMOL method. It's up to you, e.g.,

```
jmolScriptWait("select not hydrogen; set hbondsRasmol FALSE; calculate HBONDS")
```

Step 2: Only display the hbonds

```
jmolScriptWait("display connected(hbond)")
```

Step 3: Export the bonding info to JavaScript array

```
jmolGetPropertyAsArray("bondInfo")
```

You will have an array of objects each will contain the atoms connected by this hbond and the bond length.